# Installer watcher for files and registry

Tags: installation, installshield

During an application setup with InstallShield installer there are many files that copied to various locations likewise with windows registry entries as well.

Is there any way to find out exactly what file is copied to which location and what exactly registry entries are added? In other words to know the complete modification an installer does to a windows system.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like an [installation log](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/qa-log.html), where you see all this info.

Here is also some tips and tricks on [how to read a MSI log file](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/read-log.html).

Comment: This info is very useful for an MSI package. However this particular setup file i want to exam is an EXE one. So the above doesn't work.

Comment: Some Installshield setups are just EXE wrappers over an MSI, so I recommend you try the command line for creating a MSI log anyway, it might work.

If the setup is created using the old InstallShield script-based technology, I recommend you check their documentation, usually every setup vendor/builder provides some logging mechanism.

If you can't find anything the last option is always Process Monitor (it has an option to export a log file form what I remember), but you'll get "dirty". https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon